# On click go to page and execute a function

Tags: jquery, events, click

I have a page with multiple elements (page A). It is set up, so all are hidden but one. When you click on a link it will hide the one currently shown and only show the section corresponding to the link you clicked. I have that code working perfectly. I also have a separate page (page B) that has a list of links. When you click one of these links, I would like to load the page with multiple elements (page A) and show the element corresponding with the link clicked on the previous page. Below is the code I have as of now. It loads the page perfectly, but it doesn't show the appropriate element (I think because maybe that element does not exist when the code is run because the page is still loading?).

```
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function(){ //link that is clicked on
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id'); //capture id of clicked item
    window.location = 'next-page.php'; //load new page
    $('#all-elements').fadeOut(0); //hide all elements
    $('currentId').fadeIn("slow"); //show only corresponding element
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have set it up so the list item on the first page and the element I would like to show have the same id. My thinking in this is that I could capture the current id and use that value in the function as I do above. I know my problem is similar to the problem [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184648/onclick-go-to-url-then-do-something-specific), but I don't think the # technique will work for what I am doing.

Comment: Why wouldn't the hash technique work?

Comment: On line 6 of your code     $('currentId').fadeIn("slow"); //show only corresponding element
if currentId is reffering to the previously declared variable, you need to lose the single quotes, if it is a css selector, you need a . or # preceding it? Prob not the problem, but needs fixing

Comment: possible duplicate of [onclick go to url THEN do something specific](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184648/onclick-go-to-url-then-do-something-specific)

Comment: I know the other question is lacking in a concrete code example in the answer, but this question is still a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

This won't work because the code that you are running after the window.location is executed on the current page, not on the page that you are trying to load.

In order to get the page you are loading to execute any javascript, it will have to be on THAT page, not the current one.  Modify your code as such, and it should work:

On page B:

```
$(function() {
  $('li').click(function(){ //link that is clicked on
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id'); //capture id of clicked item
    window.location = 'next-page.php#' + currentId; //load new page
    return false;
  });
});
```

On page A:

```
$(function() {
  $('#all-elements').hide(); //hide all elements
  $(window.location.hash).fadeIn("slow"); //show only corresponding element
});
```

Comment: Yeah, hash is better than get param in this case, if you want to keep to js only. I am always looking for ways to ensure all users get same experience.

Comment: The issue is that because I am using jQuery to show/hide the elements, the page never changes URL. Unlike when you usually can go to a certain section of a page using an id and a #, the address mysite.com/next-page.php#currentId does not show the proper element. Does this make sense?

Comment: That's why you use jQuery to grab the hash part of the URL and determine what should be shown and what should hide.  I don't understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Send the id as a parameter on the url?

window.location = 'next-page.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id');

Answer (score -2):

Edit:  Nevermind - OP included shorthand version and I learned something new today:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

*-- REMOVE --*
Try this.  This will make sure no script is called until the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('li').click(function(){ //link that is clicked on
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id'); //capture id of clicked item
    window.location = 'next-page.php'; //load new page
    $('#all-elements').fadeOut(0); //hide all elements
    $('currentId').fadeIn("slow"); //show only corresponding element
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: `$(function() { ... });` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`